# regex remove all numbers from a paragraph except from some words

Tags: regex, r

I want to remove all numbers from a paragraph except from some words.

My attempt is using a negative look-ahead:

```
 gsub('(?!ami.12.0|allo.12)[[:digit:]]+','',
        c('0.12','1245','ami.12.0 00','allo.12 1'),perl=TRUE)
```

But this doesn't work. I get this:

```
"."      ""       "ami.. " "allo."
```

Or my expected output is:

```
"."      ""       'ami.12.0','allo.12'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use a negative lookahead here, since it will still replace when the cursor is at some point after `ami`.

What you can do is put back some matches:

```
(ami.12.0|allo.12)|[[:digit:]]+

gsub('(ami.12.0|allo.12)|[[:digit:]]+',"\\1",
        c('0.12','1245','ami.12.0 00','allo.12 1'),perl=TRUE)
```

I kept the `.` since I'm not 100% sure what you have, but keep in mind that `.` is a wildcard and will match any character (except newlines) unless you escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is actually finding every digit sequence that is not the start of "ami.12.0" or "allo.12". So for example, in your third string, it gets to the `12` in `ami.12.0` and looks ahead to see if that `12` is the start of either of the two ignored strings. It is not, so it continues with replacing it. It would be best to generalize this, but in your specific case, you can probably achieve this by instead doing a negative lookbehind for any prefixes of the words (that can be followed by digit sequences) that you want to skip. So, you would use something like this:

```
gsub('(?<!ami\\.|ami\\.12\\.|allo\\.)[[:digit:]]+','',
         c('0.12','1245','ami.12.0 00','allo.12 1'),perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks! this works also but the first solution is easily generalizable.